# ScrollView Inside ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I want to nest a small ScrollView inside my ConstraintLayout. However when I do this, all the views inside the ScrollView disappear.

The code is as below:
I have a ConstraintLayout. Inside it a ScrollView with a Vertical LinearLayout. This is populated with 5 ImageViews.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:id="@+id/cameraView">

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/thumbnails"
    android:layout_width="125dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"

    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/left" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/leftoblique" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/front" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/right_obl_initial" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/right" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
   .
   .
<!-- Other Views -->
   .
   .
   .
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

How can I fix this? Or is there an alternate way?

Comment: `However when I do this, all the views inside the ScrollView disappear.` can show any related image and possible please share your whole layout and reqired output

Comment: I run your code on my machine it's working !! please share your output

Comment: This just happened to me after upgrading to the latest Android Studio (2021.3.1 patch 1).  I'm getting Render Problems, but am annoyed as nothing had changed in my project and now...nada for certain layouts (the ones with ConstraintLayouts within ScrollView.  The bad layouts also contain TextInputLayouts which may be part of the problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, put scroll view outside the constraint layout

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/thumbnails"
    android:layout_width="125dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"

    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:id="@+id/cameraView">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/left" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/leftoblique" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/front" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/right_obl_initial" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/right" />
    </LinearLayout>

   .
   .
<!-- Other Views -->
   .
   .
   .
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: than what about this `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"`

Comment: This defeats the purpose of what I'm trying to do. I have the ScrollView and I have other views that are inside the ConstrainedLayout, but not in the ScrollView. The ScrollView is supposed to act like a small scrollable bar on the side of the main content.

Comment: Handle your layout @Nilu basic of id's

Comment: @Champandorid means remove it from your `ScrollView`